# Networking is fundamentally broken

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager, snap

I'm running 22.04 and I have troubles connecting to a WiFi network. The problems manifest differently every time, but right now it's in a state where Network manager says connected, but I cannot ping a server. My WiFi quality is pretty bad, but that is not the culprit as connecting on Android and on Ubuntu an live USB works just fine.

I've even tried reinstalling network manager in case it's its fault (installed network manager snap, removed network manager apt, rebooted), but the same thing happened. It must be some configuration deep in the system that has been changed long time ago (so the Timeshift snapshot won't cut it).

Output of `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`:
https://gitgd.com/?7befadff417fe05f#BnePJHPsm7X845XagHL7jKqkad41ovo4LiiZdn6g9PJh

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager:
Aug 03 09:39:46 asus systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Aug 03 09:39:46 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048386.4102] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Aug 03 09:39:46 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048386.4105] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.con>
Aug 03 09:39:46 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048386.4152] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Aug 03 09:39:46 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048386.4309] manager[0x55e014f23040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Aug 03 09:39:46 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048386.4313] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Aug 03 09:39:46 asus systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1134] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1134] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "asus"
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1196] dns-mgr[0x55e014f012a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1219] rfkill3: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill3) (driver ath10k_p>
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1223] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/rfkill/rfkill0) (platform drive>
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1261] manager[0x55e014f23040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1261] manager[0x55e014f23040]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1422] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1457] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1465] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1509] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1729] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1740] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi disabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1745] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1758] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1808] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1809] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1809] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.1811] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.3941] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.3944] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4034] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4147] device (wlp1s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4170] manager: (wlp1s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4192] device (wlp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4208] device (wlp1s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 38:FA:BE:1U:R2:8C (scanning)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4352] manager: (ipv6leakintrf0): new Dummy device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4782] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.4920] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Aug 03 09:39:48 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048388.5190] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now enabled by radio killswitch
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0724] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0767] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0794] policy: auto-activating connection 'pvpn-ipv6leak-protection' (d691cbb6-6d2b-4b10-b316-8c3d72b798cc)
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0802] device (ipv6leakintrf0): Activation: starting connection 'pvpn-ipv6leak-protection' (d691cbb6-6d2b-4b10-b316-8c3d72b798cc)
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0804] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0830] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0842] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0853] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.0933] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.1119] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.1124] device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.1130] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.1138] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.1155] policy: set 'pvpn-ipv6leak-protection' (ipv6leakintrf0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.1169] device (ipv6leakintrf0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.1248] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.2115] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.2116] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp1s0 created
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.2121] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.2133] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.2233] device (wlp1s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:49 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048389.2279] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:53 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048393.8448] agent-manager: agent[6a942d5ff70128bb,:1.33/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/127]: agent registered
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.1890] policy: auto-activating connection 'essid' (sd64fcviud6v8gd6rgb2hn)
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.1940] device (wlp1s0): Activation: starting connection 'essid' (sd64fcviud6v8gd6rgb2hn)
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.1944] device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2097] device (wlp1s0): set-hw-addr: set-cloned MAC address to BE:BF:16:3E:45:23 (random)
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2140] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2145] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'essid' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2145] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2174] device (wlp1s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2199] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2225] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'essid' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2227] Config: added 'ssid' value 'essid'
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2230] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2232] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2233] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2235] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2313] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2314] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2394] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2394] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2938] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2939] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2959] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.2959] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.3195] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.3195] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.6082] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.6082] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "essid"
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.6082] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.6086] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:54 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048394.6101] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 03 09:39:56 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048396.3442] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.135
Aug 03 09:39:56 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048396.3474] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:56 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048396.3544] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:56 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048396.3548] device (wlp1s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 03 09:39:56 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048396.3601] policy: set 'essid' (wlp1s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 03 09:39:56 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048396.3610] device (wlp1s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 03 09:39:56 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048396.3649] manager: startup complete
Aug 03 09:40:17 asus NetworkManager[683]: <info>  [1691048417.8750] agent-manager: agent[8cee45d5d03c1900,:1.73/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
```

Comment: is problem resolved when you plug an Ethernet cable directly to your wifi router box ?  If you computer does not have an Ethernet jack you can use an adapter to plug into your USB jack on your computer and Ethernet cable on the router ... are you using a VPN ? bc that can shut off ability to connect to say github.com domain

Comment: Scott, I don't have ethernet jack nor an adapter. VPN is disabled when trying to connect of course.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: waltinator, the output is vast and I don't see anything clearly wrong.

Comment: It must be something deep in the system.

Comment: Output of "sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager": https://gitgd.com/?7befadff417fe05f#BnePJHPsm7X845XagHL7jKqkad41ovo4LiiZdn6g9PJh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you are running Network Manager, let disable networking service:

- Find all of things which relate in /etc/network/interfaces
- Delete lines have wifi card

Reboot machine

Comment: stock Ubuntu 22.04 does not have file ` /etc/network/interfaces`